# Find $\frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=1$ if $f(x) = e^x +x$

Tags: calculus

I realize that we don't have to find the inverse explicity.

Do I set $f(x) = e^x +x$ equal to $1$ and find the formula for $x$ and differentiate?

Comment: [This](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/diff/der08/der08.html) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)$ be the inverse function. This function exists, since $f$ is increasing. We want $g'(1)$. Note that since $f(0)=1$, we have $g(1)=0$. 
We use the fact that
$$f(g(x))=x.$$
Differentiate, using the Chain Rule. We have
$$g'(x)f'(g(x))=1.$$
Now put $x=0$.

**Remark:** The above reasoning can be used to find a *general* formula for the derivative of an inverse function. We chose to go through the full derivation. Note that there is a gap in the proof: we did not show that the derivative of the inverse function *exists*.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$ You can also use implicit differentiation but this is a useful formula to know.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)=e^x+x$.

Then $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x+1=\textrm{derivative of f wrt x}$.

Now, use the fact that $$\frac{dx}{dy} \equiv \frac{1}{\left(\frac{dy}{dx} \right)},$$ where $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is the derivative of $f^{-1}$ wrt $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my hint

$$f(x)=e^x+x\rightarrow f(f^{-1}(x)) = e^{f^{-1}(x)}+f^{-1}(x)$$
$$x = e^{f^{-1}(x)}+f^{-1}(x)$$